# Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "No value."

Tags: php, mysql, json, swift, nsuserdefaults

I have created a script for the login in my application. The user types in their username and password, and then I send these values to the server. I have a php script to check the database values and then I return a json encoded array back to my app. I parse the result, store values in userdefaults and then proceed into the application. Everything was fine until I implemented another feature to return a quote from a database.

The error is extremely peculiar because **it doesn't happen every time**, but frequently enough that it is causing issue. I don't understand why

---

**Swift**:

```
let myUrl = NSURL(string: "https://www.example.com/scripts/userLogin.php");
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url:myUrl! as URL)

    request.httpMethod = "POST";
    let postString = "username=\(username)&password=\(password)";
    request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8);

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest){
        data, response, error in

        if error != nil {
            print("error=\(String(describing: error))")
            return
        }

        // Parse the results of the JSON result and naivigate to app if success
        var err: NSError?
        do {
            let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary
            if let parseJSON = json {

                let resultValue:String = parseJSON["status"] as! String;

                    if (resultValue == "Success"){

                    let storedUserID: String = parseJSON["user_id"] as! String;
                    let storedUsername: String = parseJSON["username"] as! String;
                    let storedFirstname: String = parseJSON["firstname"] as! String;
                    let storedSurname: String = parseJSON["surname"] as! String;
                    let storedUniName: String = parseJSON["uni_name"] as! String;
                    let storedUniCourse: String = parseJSON["uni_course"] as! String;
                    let storedEmail: String = parseJSON["email"] as! String;
                    let storedVerificationCode: String = parseJSON["verification_code"] as! String;
                    let theQuote: String = parseJSON["quote"] as! String

                    let array = [storedUserID, storedUsername, storedFirstname, storedSurname, storedUniName, storedUniCourse, storedEmail, storedVerificationCode, theQuote]

                    UserDefaults.standard.set(array, forKey: "UserDetailsArray");
                    UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "isUserLoggedIn");
                    UserDefaults.standard.synchronize();

                    print("Successfully logged in with:")
                    print(array)

                    DispatchQueue.main.async{
                        let mainTabBar = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "mainTabBar") as! UITabBarController;
                        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate;
                        appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = mainTabBar
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch let error as NSError {
            err = error
            print(err!);
        }
    }
    task.resume();
```

---

**PHP**:

```
$check = query_mysql("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='".$username."'");

if ($check->num_rows == 0) {
    $returnValue["status"] = "Error";
    $returnValue["message"] = "No such details found on server";
    echo json_encode($returnValue);
} else {
    while ($row = $check->fetch_assoc()){
        $storedUserID       = $row['user_id'];
        $storedUsername     = $row['username'];
        $storedfirstname    = $row['firstname'];
        $storedsurname      = $row['surname'];
        $storedPass         = $row['password'];
        $storedUniName      = $row['uni_name'];
        $storedUniCourse    = $row['uni_course'];
        $storedEmail        = $row['email'];
        $storedVerificationCode = $row['unique_code'];
        $verified           = $row['verified'];
    }

    if ($storedPass != $password ) {
        $returnValue["status"] = "Failed";
        $returnValue["message"] = "The user and password combination do not match";
        echo json_encode($returnValue);

    } elseif ($verified == 0){
        $returnValue["status"] = "Unverified";
        $returnValue["message"] = "The email associated with this account has not been verified";
        echo json_encode($returnValue);

    } else {

        // Retrieve a motivational quote
        $get_quote = query_mysql("SELECT quote FROM study_quotes ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1");

        if (!$get_quote){
            $returnValue["quote"] = "Failed";
        } else {
            while ($row = $get_quote->fetch_assoc()) $returnValue["quote"] = $row['quote'];
        }

        $returnValue["status"]              = "Success";
        $returnValue["user_id"]             = $storedUserID;
        $returnValue["username"]            = $storedUsername;
        $returnValue["firstname"]           = $storedfirstname;
        $returnValue["surname"]             = $storedsurname;
        $returnValue["uni_name"]            = $storedUniName;
        $returnValue["uni_course"]          = $storedUniCourse;
        $returnValue["email"]               = $storedEmail;
        $returnValue["verification_code"]   = $storedVerificationCode;
        echo json_encode($returnValue);
```

---

**Database**:

Has a table with id and quote (prepopulated with my own data which user has no access to. I know there will always be rows present so I never check `num_rows` but only if the query fails)

---

**Usage**:

I use UserDefaults because on the next screen, I use the 8th index (which is the quote) to set as a label as:

```
let userDetails: [String] = UserDefaults.standard.stringArray(forKey:"UserDetailsArray")!
self.quoteLabel.text = userDetails[8]
```

I seem to have a 50% success and 50% fail rate. I will receive error:

```
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "No value." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=No value.}
```

Comment: Which exact line of code is causing the error?

Comment: The catch statement of the swift script at the bottom where the error is printed: `catch let error as NSError {
                err = error
                print(err!);
            }`

Comment: Sounds like you get back bad JSON. When you get an error, convert `data` to a `String` using: `String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8)` and see what the result is.

Comment: When I print the data as a String in the catch, the data is empty. Do you know why this is? It only happens sometimes so I don't see a flaw in the script necessarily as I always login with the **same** details

Comment: Seems like your PHP script might be send back no data sometimes. You'll have to debug that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [rmaddy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1226963/rmaddy) for helping. I have found a hack that seems to work to basically re run the function everytime until the returned dataset is not empty but i'm pretty sure this isn't the correct thing to do even if it works so any help would still be appreciated:

```
            } catch let error as NSError {
            let dataSet = String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8)

            print("Trying again")
            if (dataSet?.isEmpty)!{
                self.LoginButtonTapped(self)
            }

            err = error
            print(err!);
        }
```